# Update third table by joining two table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update

I want to update third table "temp_table1" by performing some operations with other two tables "temp_table" "resource1".

temp_table:

```
+-----------+
| temp      | 
+-----------+
|  0.46574  | 
+-----------+
```

resource1:

```
+------------------+
| evaluation_value |
+------------------+
|         0.23     | 
|         0.56     |
|         0.76     |
|         0.25     |
|         0.79     |
+------------------+
```

temp_table1:

```
+-----------+
| temp      | 
+-----------+
|    0      | 
+-----------+
```

Now, I want to subtract temp value from "temp_table" with all the evaluation_value from "resource1" and save the subtracted values which are less than 0.25 in "temp_table1" and I want to update the "temp_table1" every time I run the query.

I constructed the following query for this, but I am going wrong somewhere:

```
update temp_table1 t1
set t1.temp = (
    select (e.evaluation_value - t.temp) < 0.25
    from resource1 e
    Inner join temp_table t)
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: What values are in temp to start with?  It sounds like you just want to INSERT into temp, not UPDATE.

Comment: Initially temp of "temp_table1" has a value 0.

Comment: In your example data, you have 3 rows in evaluation_value that would be less than 0.25 after subtracting the temp value (0.46574).  What 3 rows in temp are you updating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you run the query, you should clear existing values, then populate new ones:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE temp_table1
GO

INSERT INTO temp_table1
SELECT
    e.evaluation_value - t.temp
FROM temp_table t
    CROSS JOIN resource1 e
WHERE (e.evaluation_value - t.temp) < 0.25
```

That's because `UPDATE` only changes data in currently existing rows, and that is not your intention - you wish to get new results every time. Also, number of rows might vary each run, so `UPDATE` is not a good candidate here.

Another problem is with the `JOIN` type you picked: `INNER` is used in situations where there is a strict mapping from records in one table to the other (like an ID which exists in both tables) and it requires you to specify that mapping with `ON` keyword, while `CROSS` just joins everything in first table with everything in the other, like you wish to do (and so, no mapping is required).